# scala - package not found when running from command line

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala with [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do), and I have an error after trying to run one of the examples. The code:

**shapes.scala**

```
package shapes {  
  class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double) {
    override def toString() = "Point(" + x + "," + y + ")"
  }

  abstract class Shape() { 
    def draw(): Unit
  }

  class Circle(val center: Point, val radius: Double) extends Shape {
    def draw() = println("Circle.draw: " + this)
    override def toString() = "Circle(" + center + "," + radius + ")"
  }

  class Rectangle(val lowerLeft: Point, val height: Double, val width: Double)
        extends Shape {
    def draw() = println("Rectangle.draw: " + this)
    override def toString() = 
      "Rectangle(" + lowerLeft + "," + height + "," + width + ")"
  }

  class Triangle(val point1: Point, val point2: Point, val point3: Point) 
        extends Shape {
    def draw() = println("Triangle.draw: " + this)
    override def toString() = 
      "Triangle(" + point1 + "," + point2 + "," + point3 + ")"
  }
}
```

**shapes-actor.scala**

```
package shapes {
  import scala.actors._
  import scala.actors.Actor._

  object ShapeDrawingActor extends Actor {
    def act() {
      loop {
        receive {
          case s: Shape => s.draw()
          case "exit"   => println("exiting..."); exit
          case x: Any   => println("Error: Unknown message! " + x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**shapes-actor-script.scala**

```
import shapes._

ShapeDrawingActor.start()

ShapeDrawingActor ! new Circle(new Point(0.0,0.0), 1.0)
ShapeDrawingActor ! new Rectangle(new Point(0.0,0.0), 2, 5)
ShapeDrawingActor ! new Triangle(new Point(0.0,0.0),
                                 new Point(1.0,0.0),
                                 new Point(0.0,1.0))
ShapeDrawingActor ! 3.14159

ShapeDrawingActor ! "exit"
```

Now I try to run the following from the command line:

```
scalac shapes.scala shapes-actor.scala
scala -cp . shapes shapes-actor-script.scala
```

The first command compiles the classes to `.class` files in a directory named `shapes`, but the second command raises an error:

```
/Users/simon/Documents/playground/code-examples/Introdu
cingScala/shapes-actor-script.scala:3: error: not found
: value shapes
import shapes._
       ^
...
```

Is it something wrong with how I am compiling / running the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be treating Scala like it's Python. That unfortunately isn't going to work. I think you misunderstand what

```
% scala -cp . shapes shapes-actor-script.scala
```

means. When you execute that command, at least on OS X 10.11.5; Scala 2.11.8; Java 1.8.0_60; then you get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: no such file: shapes
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:194)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:205)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:67)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

It complains about not being able to find `shapes` because we've messed up the exec syntax. Remember the syntax is this `scala -cp PATHS CLASS`, where the shell will treat `PATHS` as a single argument. So the above command is telling Scala to execute the main method of a class names `shapes`, which we don't have.

We might fix this by correcting the command and joinings the paths using `:`. Like this:

```
% scala -cp .:shapes shapes-actor-script.scala
```

Now we're given this error:

```
error: error while loading ShapeDrawingActor, class file 'shapes/ShapeDrawingActor.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class ShapeDrawingActor
error: error while loading Circle, class file 'shapes/Circle.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Circle
error: error while loading Point, class file 'shapes/Point.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Point
error: error while loading Rectangle, class file 'shapes/Rectangle.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Rectangle
error: error while loading Triangle, class file 'shapes/Triangle.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Triangle
5 errors found
```

The issue here is two-fold:
- 1) Scala is going to recursively load every classfile for every directory you specify in the classpath. So we're double loading each file.
- 2) `scala` expects directory layouts for classfiles to match package layouts, which means if we list `shapes` as our sole classpath directory, and then try to load the class `shapes.Triangle` then we're really trying to find and load the file `shapes/shapes/Triangle.class`. That doesn't exist, so the script fails.

Let's remove `shapes` from the classpath and retry:

```
% scala -cp . shapes-actor-script.scala
Circle.draw: Circle(Point(0.0,0.0),1.0)
Rectangle.draw: Rectangle(Point(0.0,0.0),2.0,5.0)
Triangle.draw: Triangle(Point(0.0,0.0),Point(1.0,0.0),Point(0.0,1.0))
Error: Unknown message! 3.14159
exiting...
```

It works!

You actually have a couple of other ways to invoke this script as well. The scala command will look for class files from `.` by default, so we could have written:

```
% scala shapes-actor-script.scala
```

If you want to execute `shapes-actor-script.scala` as a true script, then the simplest way is to follow the instructions here under the heading [Script it!](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html). Just add:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
...rest of shapes-actor-script.scala
```

You then execute it on the command line as you would any other script (make sure the file is executable!):

```
% ./shapes-actor-script.scala
```

Best of luck learning scala!